# Generate signed apk fails with build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am on android studio 4. Gradle is 6.1.1. And I created a new flutter project from android studio. Then I opened the project as an android project. There is such an option in Tools->Flutter. Which resulted in gradle sync. That was successful. But when I try to generate signed apk with my keys. I get this. error

```
\path\to\my\project\build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

There is no profile directory at the given location. But there are Debug and Release directories both of which contains libs.jar. I searched all other the net for this issue. Found Nothing.

**Additional:** I can build debug apk with no issues.

Comment: following this since i weirdly encountered this now and i have no idea how it came to this all of a sudden. was it perhaps after a flutter upgrade?

Comment: I found a fix for this. Let me post it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394034/flutter-can-not-build-android-apk

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found a fix for this issue as I was searching through various issues people had reported on github regarding this.

**This is just a workaround.**

You can get two kinds of error. For me the system could not find `profile/libs.jar`, for some people the error was for `debug/libs.jar`. If the issue is **profile**, you should first run your app in profile mode and then Generate signed apk (or build and run in release mode). To run in profile mode use `flutter run --profile`. There is also a profile option under `Run` menu in Android Studio.

If the error is about `debug/libs.jar`, first build the debug version (and also the profile mode) and then try to Generate signed apk. By default, `flutter run` compiles to debug mode.

This issue evidently arises from the updated `Gradle` and `android studio gradle plugin`.

[Here is the workaround by **Jwiggiff** on the github page.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247#issuecomment-636500680)

Comment: i never even noticed there is a profile folder in src\app\ together with main folder. wonder what this is for :D profiing? i also had a prob with debug/libs.jar but once i compiled to emulator, it went back to profile/libs.jar error. somehow now i cant deploy to emulator as well. might be gradle issue ... and i think this mess started after i was forced to upgrade to gradle 6.1.1 from 5.6.2

Comment: for now i reverted back to the original 5.6.2 gradle zip and com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2 in build.gradle. that upgrade to 4.0.0 and 6.1.1.zip is the cause of the problem

Comment: Updates are supposed to make these things easier and more convenient. Now I am wasting more time figuring out what went wrong in the build system than the actual problem solving in my code. What a waste of progress.

Comment: Now everytime I have to get the apk. I need to build it three time with three options.

Comment: lol im not wasting time with that. i reverted back to the old version till they fix it. they confirmed it as a bug.

Comment: Running Run->Profile and then I was able to build apk successfully

Comment: as @chitgoks mentioned I replaced 
com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0 ~> 3.5.2

That did the trick. The error is gone now!

Answer (score 15):

This problem is with latest gradle 4.0.0

Switch from classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'`

or `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'` **(Worked for me)**

Comment: I'm already in 3.5.0 but still getting error

Answer (score 10):

If you don't care about `lintOptions` you can add this code in app's `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    lintOptions { 
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't actually solve the problem. It justs skip the test. Means the actual still persists

Comment: @FardeenKhan Already said above, Use it only if you don't care about `lintOptions `

Answer (score 1):

this will work.

flutter build apk --debug &&
flutter build apk --profile &&
flutter build apk --release

but test the apk before sharing it.

even it doesn't work the change the gradle from 4.x to 3.6.x this will work.

Comment: How do you recreate the android folder?

Comment: just delete android folder and run the command flutter create .

Answer (score 1):

This should also work fine

```
flutter build apk --profile
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick

Run terminal for current flutter project, then type

```
flutter run
```

to get this success result :

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        22.7s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
```

then, type

```
flutter build apk
```

to get

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      41.8s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (23.6MB).
```

then, install this `Release APK` to device.

```
flutter install build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

Now, you got Release App on your device.

p/s : This case skip error

- `Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.`
- `Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes`
- `Execution failed for JetifyTransform`
- `Transform's input file does not exist`

you already got.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot that I'm using flavors. Maybe this caused the issue.
Now I let flutter build the app with the following command:

```sh
flutter build apk --flavor <flavorname> -t <path/to/main.dart>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Permanent fix

To fix this issue permanently, type in terminal

1. `flutter doctor`

This will give you summary like this

[image]

You need to fix all those red marks!!

### Fixing android licenses

type  `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

if you encounter this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
```

Try to install Android SDK command-line tools from Android Studio (Tools > SDK Manager)

1. Unfold Appearance & Behavior
2. Unfold System Settings
3. Click Android SDK
4. Click tab of SDK Tools
5. Check Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)
6. Click Apply button

[image]

Then run once again

`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

### Fixing Flutter plugin not installed

1. Check your Android Studio Version (For Mac go to ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio{Version}. In my case, the {Version} is 2020.3)
2. Then type

> `ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio2020.3`

This command just redirects flutter doctor to the different folder to find plugins (where they are now). This is called symbolic link

### Fixing unable to find bundled Java version

This solution is for Mac User

1. Find your local Java version by typing `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
2. Set Java_Home path by typing `/usr/libexec/java_home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home`
3. Type all of these in terminal

> ```
> cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
> ln -s ../jre jdk
> ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
> ```

4. Finally run `flutter doctor -v` to see all the details changes

### Happy Ending

After fixing all those issues, run

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

to build release apk

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```