# Is it possible to generate flutter .ipa file in flutlab?

Tags: generate

I am new in flutter. I am able to generate .apk file from android studio. I have already searched from google but can not find a suitable solution except on flutlab. I am able to build ios debug from flutlab but can not generate .IPA file. can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate signed apk fails with build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154149/generate-signed-apk-fails-with-build-app-intermediates-flutter-profile-libs-jar)

Comment: No, this is for android,...

Answer (score 3):

flutlab.io generates IOS simulator bundle. This bundle has .ZIP extension and can be used on any desktop or cloud IOS Emulator. For example you can upload it on appetize.io cloud IOS emulator. IPA generation is not available on flutlab as of January'21.

Comment: Are there any other services from where I can get the IPA?