# Flutter AppCenter Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+ build issue

Tags: android, bash, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to get the flutter app to build in [AppCenter.ms](https://AppCenter.ms) but I'm stuck with a gradle command cleaning the intermediates folder.

I have followed these tutorials to set it up:

- https://www.rocksolidknowledge.com/articles/using-appcenter-for-flutter-projects
- https://buildflutter.com/deploying-flutter-apps-via-appcenter/
- https://medium.com/@subodhpushpak/flutter-continuous-build-deployment-using-appcenter-e105d00e6f9c

I have added a `productFlavor` called `appCenter` to accommodate this library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appcenter_bundle

Here is my `appcenter-post-clone.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Place this script in project/android/app/

cd ..

# fail if any command fails
set -e
# debug log
set -x

cd ..
git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH

flutter channel stable
flutter doctor

# prevent missing flutter.jar error
flutter precache `pwd`/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine

# Set APP_CENTER_VERSION_MODIFIER if you want to modify the version name
# to x.y.z-${APP_CENTER_VERSION_MODIFIER}
BUILD_NAME=$(grep -E '^version' pubspec.yaml | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d '[:space:]')
if [ ! -z "$APPCENTER_BUILD_ID" ]
then
  BUILD_NAME=${BUILD_NAME}.${APPCENTER_BUILD_ID}
fi
if [ ! -z "$APP_CENTER_VERSION_MODIFIER" ]
then
  BUILD_NAME=${BUILD_NAME}-${APP_CENTER_VERSION_MODIFIER}
fi

flutter build apk --debug --flavor appCenter
flutter build apk --release --flavor appCenter --build-name=${BUILD_NAME} -t lib/main.dart

mkdir -p android/app/build/outputs/apk/
mv build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-appcenter-release.apk $_
```

The error occurs when the `appcenter-post-clone.sh` script has finished and it is running gradle afterwards:

```
+ flutter build apk --debug --flavor appCenter
Running "flutter pub get" in s...                                  11.2s

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleAppCenterDebug'...                 
Gradle 6.7
...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAppCenterDebug'...                   193.4s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-appcenter-debug.apk.

+ flutter build apk --release --flavor appCenter --build-name=1.42 -t lib/main.dart
Running "flutter pub get" in s...                                  15.7s

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleAppCenterRelease'...               
Gradle 6.7
...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAppCenterRelease'...                 104.7s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-appcenter-release.apk (25.9MB).
+ mkdir -p android/app/build/outputs/apk/
+ mv build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-appcenter-release.apk android/app/build/outputs/apk/
+ mv -v android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-appcenter-release.apk android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk
android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-appcenter-release.apk -> android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk

//SCRIPT HAS FINISHED
//RUNNING NORMAL GRADLE

Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper script
Version      : 1.128.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613720)
==============================================================================
(node:3364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
...
(node:3364) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
[command]/.../android/gradlew -DAPPCENTER_BUILD_VERSION=42 -DMOBILECENTER_BUILD_VERSION=42 -p android clean :app:assembleAppCenterRelease :app:lintAppCenterRelease
...
> Task :app:lintVitalAppCenterRelease FAILED
Resolved com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:27.1.0 in :app:lintClassPath 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalAppCenterRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:appCenterDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /.../build/app/intermediates/flutter/appCenterDebug/libs.jar.
         > Transform's input file does not exist: /.../build/app/intermediates/flutter/appCenterDebug/libs.jar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)
```

The issue:

```
Transform's input file does not exist: /.../intermediates/flutter/appCenterDebug/libs.jar
```

I have come across this SO post:
[Generate signed apk fails with build\app\intermediates\flutter\profile\libs.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154149/generate-signed-apk-fails-with-build-app-intermediates-flutter-profile-libs-jar)
which points to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247#issuecomment-636500680

The "solution" there is to first run `flutter build apk --debug` and then `flutter build apk --release`

This will in theory generate the `intermediates` directory for both `appCenterDebug` and `appCenterRelease` with the required files.

Testing it locally by running `gradlew lintAppCenterDebug` and then `gradlew lintAppCenterRelease` works.

Both the flutter commands builds successfully.

The problem is with this line when gradle starts to run:

```
[command]/.../android/gradlew -DAPPCENTER_BUILD_VERSION=42 -DMOBILECENTER_BUILD_VERSION=42 -p android clean :app:assembleAppCenterRelease :app:lintAppCenterRelease
```

It does a clean in the command, which deletes the `intermediates` directory (so this `/.../appCenterDebug/libs.jar` does not exist anymore) and only builds the `:app:...Release` versions. It then continues and breaks giving the `input file does not exist` error.

How can this problem be resolved?

How is it possible to remove the `clean` part from the gradle command? (I can't find it anywhere)

1. I have tested this exact command locally, and breaks.
2. Regenerate the `intermediates` content by running the two gradle lint commands
3. Run the same gradle command but without the `clean` and it works.

Debug, Release builds works fine locally and in appcenter(until gradle is run and removes the required files)

### **ADDITIONAL INFO**

---

**pubspec.yaml**:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        defaultKey {
            /* truncated */
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.defaultKey
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "distribute"
    productFlavors {
        appCenter {
            dimension "distribute"
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to build successfully.

I removed:

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appcenter_bundle
- productFlavors

I changed:

- gradle plugin to an older version `< 4.0.0`

Build is successful

Only with Gradle Plugin `4.0.0+` appCenter wants the `intermediates/flutter/appCenterDebug/libs.jar` to be present but this command ran after the flutter script ran, deletes it:

```
[command]/.../android/gradlew -DAPPCENTER_BUILD_VERSION=42 -DMOBILECENTER_BUILD_VERSION=42 -p android clean :app:assembleAppCenterRelease :app:lintAppCenterRelease
```

### **File changes**

---

**app/appcenter-post-clone.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Place this script in project/android/app/

cd ..

# fail if any command fails
set -e
# debug log
set -x

cd ..
git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH

flutter channel stable
flutter doctor

# Set APP_CENTER_VERSION_MODIFIER if you want to modify the version name
# to x.y.z-${APP_CENTER_VERSION_MODIFIER}
BUILD_NAME=$(grep -E '^version' pubspec.yaml | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d '[:space:]')
if [ ! -z "$APPCENTER_BUILD_ID" ]
then
  BUILD_NAME=${BUILD_NAME}.${APPCENTER_BUILD_ID}
fi
if [ ! -z "$APP_CENTER_VERSION_MODIFIER" ]
then
  BUILD_NAME=${BUILD_NAME}-${APP_CENTER_VERSION_MODIFIER}
fi
./update-app-settings.sh

flutter build apk --release --build-name=${BUILD_NAME} -t lib/main.dart

mkdir -p android/app/build/outputs/apk/
mv build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk $_
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        defaultKey {
            /* truncated */
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.defaultKey
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Comment: what do we looses by downgrading to such an old versions? any drawbacks?